# Selecionar linha no datagridwier e gravar no banco de dados

Tags: c#

Tenho um datagridviwer populado por um query do banco de dados sql, nesse datagrid tenho uma coluna com um chekbox, agora vem minha duvida, como faço pra gravar no banco de dados quando a linha tiver sido selecionada pelo usuario no chekbox.

segue minha tela do datagrid
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código hoje onde faço o insert no banco mas sem funcionar o chekbox

```
private void ncheklist()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TBL_CHEKLIST (N_NOTA, CLIENTE, TRANSP, VOLUME, N_CHEKLIST, EMISSAO) 
                      VALUES (@NOTA, @CLIENTE, @TRANSP, @VOLUME, @CHEKLIST, @EMISSAO)";
    cmd.Connection = conex1;
    conex1.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NOTA", this.txt_nota.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CLIENTE", this.txt_cliente.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TRANSP", this.txt_transp.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VOLUME", this.txt_volume.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CHEKLIST", this.txt_nchklist.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EMISSAO", Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dtinicial.Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "")));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conex1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para verificar se a coluna do CHECKBOX está marcada eu faço da seguiinte forma:

```
// varrendo o dataGrid
for (Int32 index = 0; index < meuGrid.Rows.Count; index++)
{
   //verifica se a linha do grid está com o checkbox ativado
   //cells[0] = corresponde a primeira coluna, ou seja a que possui o CHECKBOX
   if (bool.Parse(meuGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()) == true)
   {
      // executa ação de inserção no banco de dados
   }
}
```

Comment: vnbrs, obrigado por editar, onde clico para editar para c# geralmente coloco entre as tags "code".

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, testei aqui e funcionou, só não consegui fazer pegar o valor das colunas e fazer o insert, ou seja não consegui fazer para oi comando pegar o valor de cada célula e fazer o insert no banco nos campos corretos.

Comment: Esquece o comentario acima, ajustei aqui o codigo e deu certo o insert muito obrigado.

Comment: Junior Guerreiro, fico feliz que tenha conseguido resolver, Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

O nome da sua coluna `N_CHEKLIST` está diferente onde está setando o nome do parâmetro `@CHEKLIST`. No caso teria que ser igual para ambos.

Respondendo sua pergunta, você precisaria tratar no código como 'deseja' salvar no banco.

Exemplo:

```
TBL_CHEKLIST objChek = new TBL_CHEKLIST();

objChek.N_CHEKLIST= (txt_nchklist.Checked == true ? "S" : "N");
```

No `Insert/Update` fazer o devido tratamento

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(N_CHEKLIST) ? new SqlParameter("@N_CHEKLIST",txt_nchklist.Text) : new SqlParameter("@N_CHEKLIST", DBNull.Value))};
```

Comment: Me desculpe Igor mas obrigado pela atenção, a sua resposta não ficou muito clara pra mim, isso porque ainda sou novato em c# então não entendi muito bem o que vc quis dizer com " você precisaria tratar no código como 'deseja' salvar no banco." o caso do parâmetro cheklist tudo bem entendi, só não entendi como fazer par dizer para o meu código que quando na coluna seleciona o chekbox estiver marcado eu gravo os dados da linha na minha tabela e se não estiver marcado e não faço nada.

Comment: Acho que o problema e o seguinte quando eu populo o datagridview, populo com uma tabela e quando vou gravar no banco eu não enxergo mais esta tabela, eu gravo as informações em outra tabela no banco.

Comment: Por favor alguém tem mais alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso no meu código, a ideia do Igor acima não consegui fazer funcionar no meu código, se alguém mais tiver outra ideia agradeço.